# arborjs в angular, как подключить библиотеку?

Tags: jquery, angular, graph

Я использую библиотеку arborjs для построения графов (Я не смог найти установку через npm), как я могу использовать эту библиотеку у себя в проекте?

```
Graph() {   
 const sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(1000); 
         sys.parameters({gravity: true}); 
         sys.renderer = this.rendererCanvas('#viewport');
...
}
```

Выше код инициализации системы, который находится в файле * .component.ts file.

Не может найти `arbor.ParticleSystem (1000).`

библиотека в проекте находится в: "src / lib / arbor"

директория где нужно ее вызвать: "src/app/*.component.ts"

jquary подключено. Так как она нужна для работы 'Arbor'

Правка:

Если просто поместить на html подключения, и зайти на localhost проекта, то не работает, а если просто html запустить, то работает, есть какие нибудь идеи?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/arbor.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/arborjs

Comment: @Konst это не оно, http://arborjs.org сайт плагина, там гиты разные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло следующее.
в файле 'angular.json":

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "src/assets/lib/arbor/lib/arbor.js"
            ]
```

в файле 'index.html", который находится в папке проекта 'src':

```
 <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/lib/arbor/lib/arbor.js"></script>
```

в файле '*.component.ts', после основных импортов:

```
declare var $: any;
declare var arbor: any;
```

я не претендую на лучшее решение, но может это кому еще поможет.